# "Other C Flags" in Xcode 4 Cocoa Static Library project

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

in Xcode 4, I created a sub project in my iOS project and made it a "Cocoa Static Library". In the Project/Target Build Settings, there is no option for "Other C Flags".  Actually, there are no compiler options at all.  Can anyone explain why this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the Basic option selected on the upper left instead of all?
[image: Is the Basic option selected on the upper left instead of all?]

Comment: Don't know how I missed that.. long day I guess. Thanks for pointing it out so nicely. :)

Comment: You know, in Xcode 4.3 (and 4.3.1), this is still a problem, and it's not because the build setting is hidden by a selection of Basic. Showing All, Combined, there is still no Other C Flags option. Vexing. Will ask the question more specifically for Xcode 4.3 to see if I can get an answer.